# Integrating with trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus

I know how to integrate $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(9x)\mathrm{d}x}{1+\sin^2(9x)}$$ but I don't understand how to get the exact value $\frac{\pi}{36}$, just the decimal approximation.

Comment: Techniques include tangent half angle subs, expanding the numerator using trig identities, using complex numbers and Euler's Formula, using the transformation $x \to - x$. You'll almost surely have to use multiple of these and others, but should give a starting point for things to try.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+cos(9x)%2F(1%2Bsin%5E2(x))+dx+x%3D0+to+pi%2F2) begs to differ.  Indeed, WolframAlpha even has the indefinite integral.

Comment: $$\int\frac{\cos(9x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}dx=C+985\arctan[\sin[x]]-816\sin[x]-140/3\sin[3 x]-24/5\sin[5 x]-4/7\sin[7 x]$$

Comment: The answer I get from integrating is $\frac{1}{9}arctan(sin(\frac{9\pi}{2}))$. I just didnt realize $\frac{9\pi}{2}$ reduces to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Observing that $(\sin 9x)' = 9\cos 9x$ and that $\int \frac{1}{1 +y^2}dy = \arctan y + c$, we get the indefinite integral $\frac 19 \arctan (\sin 9x) + c$, and when you apply the bounds to this, you get the required result.

EDIT: and to answer the OP's comment, $\sin \theta = \sin (\theta \pm 2n\pi)$, so this is why $\sin \frac{9\pi}{2} = \sin \frac{\pi}{2}$.